# Explicación funcionamiento método super() en Java

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con el metodo super pero la verdad no se que hacer para que funcione. Ayuda!

```
public class ClassUno {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    ///// Clases Internas   ////

    class Primera {

        int k;
        public Primera( int s ) {
            k = s;
        }
    }

    class Segunda extends Primera {

        public Segunda() {
            super();
        }

        public Segunda( int n ) {
            k = n;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Creo que en lo que te equivocas o me das a mi entender aunque no te expliques bien en el problema que tienes..Es que a mi parecer en el constructor de "Segunda" tienes que pasarle los parámetros de la clase padre osea el int para que funcione

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cuando utilizas herencia en Java, en los constructores que declaras en las clases hijas siempre deben llamar a `super(args)` o a `this(args)`, donde:

- `super(args)` hace referencia a un constructor de la clase padre.
- `this(args)` hace referencia a un constructor definido en la clase actual.
- `args` en `super(args)` y `this(args)` se refiere a los posibles argumentos que requiera el constructor que se está llamando.

Ten en cuenta que en los constructores de una clase hija, al menos un constructor debe llamar a `super()` y los demás constructores pueden llamar a `super()` o `this()`.

Esto se explica en la [especificación de Java, capítulo 8 Clases, parte 8.8 Declaraciones de Constructores, sección 8.8.7 Cuerpo del Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7) (contenido del enlace en inglés).

Sabiendo esto, veamos la definición de `Primera`:

```
class Primera {
    int k;

    public Primera(int s) {
        k = s;
    }
}
```

Se puede observar que solo existe **1 constructor** que recibe 1 argumento de tipo `int`. Ahora veamos los constructores de `Segunda`:

```
class Segunda extends Primera {
    public Segunda() {
        /*
            error de compilación
            Causa: No existe un constructor en la clase padre
            sin argumentos
        */
        super();
    }


    public Segunda( int n ) {
        /*
            error de compilación
            Causa: no se llama a super(args) o this(args) en la primera línea
        */
        k = n;
    }
}
```

Esto puede tener múltiples soluciones dependiendo del diseño de tus clases. Aquí un ejemplo:

```
class Segunda extends Primera {
    public Segunda() {
        /*
            se llama al constructor Segunda(int)
            y se envía como argumento 0
        */
        this(0);
    }


    public Segunda( int n ) {
        /*
            se llama al constructor de la clase padre
            con argumento n. En la clase padre, va a inicializar
            el valor del campo k con el valor de la variable n
        */
        super(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, super bien explicado, muchisimas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

creeria que tu problema esta en que cuando pones el super tenes que pasarle como parametro los atributos que tiene en la primera clase. En tu caso es la variable "s". Entonces te quedaria asi :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
```

**Clases Internas**

```
class Primera {

    int k;


    public Primera( int s ) {

        k = s;
    }
}
```

```
class Segunda extends Primera {

// aca es donde le pasas por parametro la variable s. si tuvieras mas variables deberias de pasarle todas las variables como parametro 

    public Segunda() {


        super(s);
    }


    public Segunda( int n ) {

        k = n;
    }
}
```

Comment: El segundo constructor `public Segunda(int n)` no compilará puesto que no se llama a `super` ni a `this` en la primera línea de su código. El primer constructor `Segunda()` no funciona puesto que no se sabe qué es `s`.

Answer (score 0):

En el constructor sin parámetros de la clase Segunda estás llamando al constructor sin parámetros de la clase Primera pero no declaraste dicho constructor y esto es necesario porque, al definir un constructor parametrizado en la clase Primera, el compilador de Java ya no te agrega el constructor por defecto (sin parámetros) en dicha clase, por lo que deberías agregarlo.