# Confirmación si es correcto con lo que pide el enunciado

Tags: java, poo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La foto sería el enunciado a continuación paso mi codigo. Si por favor me pudieran confirmar si esta bien o ven algun error. ¿También quería preguntar si es correcto ponerlo todo las variables con private?.

```
 public class Flight {
  private String nombre;
  private String descripcion;
  private double precio;
  private boolean pasajero_residente;

  public Flight(String nombre, String descripcion, double precio){
   this.nombre = nombre;
   this.descripcion = descripcion
   this.precio = precio
  }
 

  public void setResident(boolean pasajero_residente) {
    this.pasajero_residente = pasajero_residente;
   }
}
```

Añado los datos que lleva  tourist product en la foto para que lo vean mas claro pero llevaria un nombre,descripcion, precios.**(no estoy preguntando por el codigo de TouristProduct lo pongo porque antes me preguntaron que contiene TouristProduct por eso paso la foto)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que hace referencia a la herencia en Java. Intenta con extends TouristProduct, y luego crea un método al que le pasas como parámetro un booleano (pasajero_residente), y te retorne otro booleano, para indicar si tiene o no acceso al descuento. Un saludo

Comment: @Dramaturgo TouristProduct lleva un nombre único, una descripción, un precio de venta (double) y un posible descuento (double). Edito mi pregunta para que veas lo que tiene

Comment: @Dramaturgo ya los añadi lo que lleva

Comment: @JakintsuIheslari gracias por tu respuesta,  entiendo que me falta el extend, pero no entiendo lo que dices que retorne otro booleano.

Comment: @Isma Si alguna respuesta te ha servido para solucionar tu duda/problema, márcala como "aceptada". No edites la pregunta para añadir los cambios hechos a causa de una respuesta porque crea incongruencias. Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más detalles

Answer (score 5):

la clase  `TouristProduct`  tiene los datos nombre y descripcion por ende los declaras en esa clase y los heredas en la clase **Flight** usando `extends`,como estas heredando esos datos haces referencia en el constructor usando `super`  en vez de `this` ,tu constructor estaría listo ,ahora en la clase `TouristProduct`  declara los métodos abstractos y por último en la clase **Flight** dales forma a esos metodos

Detalle del funcionamiento de this() and  super():
[Explicación funcionamiento método super() en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7941/explicaci%C3%B3n-funcionamiento-m%C3%A9todo-super-en-java)

```
public class Flight extends  TouristProduct {
  private double precio;
  private boolean pasajero_residente;

  public Flight(String nombre, String descripcion, double precio){
   super(nombre,descripcion);
   this.precio = precio
  }
 
  public void setResident(boolean pasajero_residente) {
    this.pasajero_residente = pasajero_residente;
   }

     //metodos abstractos heredados de la clase TouristProduct
}
```

Comment: Por completar esa respuesta: no uses `pasajero_residente` como nombre de atributo. Sigue la convención de Java y usa `pasajeroResidente` (notación camelCase) o simplemente `resident` (para coincidir con el setter)

Comment: @Isma el segundo enunciado que agregaste indica que tu clase ```TouristProduct```,indica que algunos o todos los métodos que se detallan son abstractos,si ese es el caso debes saber que un método abstracto puede ser heredado

Comment: @Dramaturgo muchas gracias por la aportacion edite la pregunta que hice y puse debajo lo que iria despues por si me puedes confirmar

Comment: @PabloLozano muchas gracias por tu aportacion del camelCase la tendre en cuenta
Edite mi pregunta y puse debajo la continuacion de la respuesta por si le quieres echar un vistazo tambien

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos en especial @Dramaturgo

Comment: Saludos @Dramaturgo, noté que cada vez que realizas una edición dejas un comentario en el espacio "**Resumen de la edición**", éste espacio es para aclarar que es lo que editaste y no así para referirte al autor, si quieres dejar un comentario al autor siempre puedes hacerlo debajo de su publicación. ;)

Comment: Saludos @Israel-ICM ,lo tendré en cuenta ,gracias por la aclaración :)

Answer (score 3):

Creo que te faltaría heredar de la clase TuristProduct:

```
public class Flight extends TouristProduct {

    // El resto de cosas...

}
```

Sobre lo de utilizar esas variables en private, depende de cuál se el objetivo.

En Java se suele acceder a los atributos de los objetos mediante getters y setters.

Comment: Con los puntos te refieres a poner un extend no?. Seria solo eso o me falta algo mas?